# Any handy way to create a list of strings in python without using quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there any handy way to create a list of strings, without using quotes.
Actually every time when I have to type for creating a long list, it always bothers me to add quotes and sometime I miss it.

For example:

```
a=['foo','bar', 'xyz','abc'............'pqr']
```

if `a` is long list, then to type such list is pain.

I want to directly use something like:

```
a= [foo,bar,xyz,pqr,abc,klm,........]
```

Just like a comma separated list.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it is you're asking. String literals require quotes. Could you give an example of what it is you're up to?

Comment: the best way would probably be to write each element in a text file and form the list by reading it from there

Answer (score 4):

If the strings are composed of single tokens - with no space between them, you can just write a long string and then use "split" to get a list:

```
class Person:
    __slots__ = "name age address number".split()
```

And, in the same spirit, for more complex strings you can do the same and just use any other separator you like - just use split passing the optional `sep` parameter. And you can also use multi-line strings =with the  `"""` strign quoting in Python and use "\n" as the split separator, s you get one string per line.

(To keep your example:

```
a = "foo bar xyz abc pqr".split()
```

)

Another, not totally unrelated way of typing less quote characters is when declaring literal inline dictionaries - instead of the usual

```
{"xyz": 1, "abc": 2, "def": 3}
```

One can type much less by using the `dict` built-in itself:

```
dict(xyz=1, abc=2, def=3)
```

Comment: It's "...strings comprise single..." or "...strings are composed of single...", by the way.

Comment: Any reason you're using `__slots__` with a `class` here as an example... surely `a = 'foo bar xyz'.split()` would be more appropriate in context?

Comment: Also might be worth noting that if you use `"""` strings, you can put the tokens on separate lines and `split` will still handle it.

Comment: @JonClements:  check the question and answer history and posting timestamps and you will knw the reason:  the 1st version of the question did not have an example. I used the `__slots__` because it is my "real World" use case for this.

Comment: Note that using `dict()` instead of a literal requires that all your keys be valid Python identifiers.

Answer (score 4):

String literals *require* quotes. Your sole alternative might be to create a single literal with comma separated values (requiring of course the initial quotes) and *then* operate on that to break it down into sub-strings.

For example:

```
s = "foo,bar,xyz,pqr,abc,klm"
```

By splitting on the `','` you can then populate a list:

```
l = s.split(',')
```

to contain the sub-strings:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'xyz', 'pqr', 'abc', 'klm']
```

Comment: Probably better in context to `.split` the literal directly.